# How to create an Audit model with a link to survey ID and question/answer using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I am working on an application where I can create lists of questions and then answer them (similar to google forms). So I have a survey page where I can create questions dynamically, it works.
When I create a new audit, I need to choose which survey it will be created from. This page also provides questions and answer forms for each question.

The Audit should be created only if there were answers to all the questions in the Survey. Now in the Audit model I only store the survey ID from which I need to create the audit itself.

The question is how to correctly create such a model(id value is enough) and program the creation of a new Audit.

Checklist model:

```rb
class Checklist < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :questions, dependent: :destroy

  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 40 }
  validates :description, presence: true
end
```

Question model

```rb
class Question < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :checklist

  has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { in: 12..40 }
  validates :description, presence: true
end
```

Answer model

```rb
class Answer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :question
  validates :answer, presence: true
  validates :comment, presence: true, length: { maximum: 40 }
end
```

Routes (Not sure if this is right)

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'checklists#index'
  
  resources :checklists do
    resources :questions, only: [:create] do
      resources :answers, only: [:create, :destroy]
    end
  end

  resources :checklists do
    resources :audits
  end
  
  resources :audits, only: [:index]
end
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please correct typo in routes for `exept`

Comment: Oh yes, I use only `only: [:create, :destroy]` for resources :answers